# WPF - Events on a ControlTemplate?

Tags: wpf, controltemplate, routed-events

Does anyone know why I can't set an event on a control template??

For example, the following line of code will not compile. It does this with any events in a control template.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="DefaultTemplate" TargetType="ContentControl">
   <StackPanel Loaded="StackPanel_Loaded">

   </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

I am using a MVVM design pattern and the control here is located in a ResourceDictionary that is added to the application's MergedDictionaries.

Comment: For anyone with the same question, I am using a Style and EventSetter as an alternative, although I still would like to know why I can't set the Event directly on the control if I'm using a ControlTemplate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to declare event handlers inside ControlTemplate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140563/how-to-declare-event-handlers-inside-controltemplate)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Does anyone know why I can't set an event on a control template??

Actually, you can... But where would you expect the event handler to be defined ? The `ResourceDictionary` has no code-behind, so there is no place to put the event handler code. You can, however, create a class for your resource dictionary, and associate it with the `x:Class` attribute :

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Class="MyNamespace.MyClass"
                    xmlns=...>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="DefaultTemplate" TargetType="ContentControl">
       <StackPanel Loaded="StackPanel_Loaded">

       </StackPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

C# code :

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public partial class MyClass : ResourceDictionary
    {
        void StackPanel_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

(you might also need to change the build action of the resource dictionary to "Page", I don't remember exactly...)

Comment: That is what I currently have... A class for the ResourceDictionary with it's Build Action set to Page. Only difference I can see is I didn't declare it public, but changing that didn't help at all.

Comment: And what's the problem exactly ? Do you get an error message ?

Comment: When I go to run the program, it throws a NullReferenceException (it compiles fine). It must have something to do with my design pattern because I tried creating a simple test case and its working fine. My main app overwrites app.xaml's OnStartup to load a bunch of different ResourceDictionaries, creates an instance of MainWindow, sets its DataContext, then calls MainWindow.Show() - The last line is where I'm getting the exception. Moving the Event from the ControlTemplate to an EventSetter gets rid of the error.

Comment: The ResourceDictionary I am testing with defines a DataTemplate for a custom object, and in that DataTemplate there is a custom UserControl. The UserControl.Resources contains the ControlTemplate containing the event, and the UserControl.Content contains a ContentControl that references the ControlTemplate.

Comment: Then you need to take the ControlTemplate to an other file

Comment: Why is that? I was hoping to avoid that because sections of the application are modular and I wanted to keep all the resources for a section together in one file.