# How to declare event handlers inside ControlTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following `ControlTemplate`:

```
<ControlTemplate>
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="400">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="18" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="45" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Template="{StaticResource watermark}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="4,0,0,4" Tag="Number" />
        <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Template="{StaticResource watermark}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="4,0,0,4" Tag="Login" />
        <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Template="{StaticResource watermark}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="4,0,0,4" Tag="Password" />
        <Button Grid.Column="4" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Content="Add" Margin="4,0,0,4" Click="AddUser_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

How should I write `AddUser_Click` to get access to textboxes `Text` properties?

**upd:** just to make it clear. I know how to connect `Click` event handler here. The question is how to read contents of textboxes in it since I cant give them name because they are in a template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to the templatedparent (SelectedItem, FindVisualParent etc.) you can do this if you apply Names to the TextBoxes. Example if ControlTemplate is for ComboBoxItem.

```
private void AddUser_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBoxItem comboBoxItem = GetVisualParent<ComboBoxItem>(button);
    TextBox textBox = comboBoxItem.Template.FindName("numberTextBox", comboBoxItem) as TextBox;
    //...
}
```

Another way to get the TextBoxes within the ControlTemplate would be to use the Visual Tree. Something like this

```
private void AddUser_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;
    Grid parentGrid = GetVisualParent<Grid>(button);
    List<TextBox> textBoxes = GetVisualChildCollection<TextBox>(parentGrid);
    foreach (TextBox textBox in textBoxes)
    {
        if (textBox.Tag == "Number")
        {
            // Do something..
        }
        else if (textBox.Tag == "Login")
        {
            // Do something..
        }
        else if (textBox.Tag == "Password")
        {
            // Do something..
        }
    }
}
```

And an implementation of GetVisualParent and GetVisualChildCollection

```
public static T GetVisualParent<T>(object childObject) where T : Visual
{
    DependencyObject child = childObject as DependencyObject;
    // iteratively traverse the visual tree
    while ((child != null) && !(child is T))
    {
        child = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);
    }
    return child as T;
}

public static List<T> GetVisualChildCollection<T>(object parent) where T : Visual
{
    List<T> visualCollection = new List<T>();
    GetVisualChildCollection(parent as DependencyObject, visualCollection);
    return visualCollection;
}
private static void GetVisualChildCollection<T>(DependencyObject parent, List<T> visualCollection) where T : Visual
{
    int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
        if (child is T)
        {
            visualCollection.Add(child as T);
        }
        else if (child != null)
        {
            GetVisualChildCollection(child, visualCollection);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 23):

What you could do is give Button a name "PART_Button". Then override OnApplyTemplate method in control. In code, you can do

```
var btn = this.Template.FindName("PART_Button", this) as Button;
btn.Click += ...
```

Answer (score 6):

The event handler is searched in the class that the [`x:Class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752309.aspx) directive of current file points to, which allows you adding the event handler inline without bothering to override the class and override the [`OnApplyTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.onapplytemplate.aspx) with adding handlers hassle, regardless of the place that you declare the ControlTemplate.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Button Content="asdf">
    <Button.Style>
      <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
              <Button Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Click="Button_Click"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
      </Style>
    </Button.Style>
  </Button>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Windows;
namespace WpfApplication1
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
  /// </summary>
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      MessageBox.Show("Button clicked!");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had no luck finding my checkbox, PART_CheckBox, with  the

```
 this.Template.FindName("control name", this)
```

method
but

```
 GetTemplateChild("control name")
```

worked.

'ResourceDictionary' stub

```
<Style x:Key="OGrid" TargetType="{x:Type local:OrientationGrid}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:OrientationGrid}" x:Name="PART_Control">
                    <CheckBox  x:Name="PART_CheckBox"/>
                            ...
```

Custom Control, OrientationGrid, stub:

```
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        CheckBox chkbx = GetTemplateChild("PART_CheckBox") as CheckBox;
        chkbx.Checked += Chkbx_Checked;
    }

    private void Chkbx_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Event Raised");
    }
    ...
```

answer based on:
[WPF get element from template in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30224124/wpf-get-element-from-template-in-code)