# WPF get element from template in code

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to get an element (a path) which is the template of my content control. I want to get a reference on "contour_forme" but every solution found on the internet returns null. I've tried overriding OnApplyTemplate but still null :

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        var template = this.pion_test.Template;
        var contour = GetTemplateChild("contour_forme");
        forme_path = template.FindName("contour_forme", this.pion_test) as Path;
        Path path = FindVisualChild<Path>(this.pion_test);
        var test = this.pion_test.FindName("contour_forme");
        var test2 = this.pion_test.Template.FindName("contour_forme", this.pion_test);
    }
```

my xaml :

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}" x:Key="StylePion">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                        <Grid Width="33" Height="34">
                            <Path x:Name="contour_forme"
                              Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                              StrokeThickness="1"
                              Stretch="Uniform"
                              Width="28"

                              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                  Margin="0,-1,0,0"
                                  RenderTransformOrigin="0.59,0.5"
                              Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                              Data="M17.36,24.623c-2.142-0.006-4.153-0.552-5.907-1.506l0,0l-0.076-0.046
        c-1.952-1.08-3.57-2.673-4.692-4.589L0,11.942l7.126-6.514c1.077-1.584,2.519-2.896,4.2-3.84l0.127-0.077l0,0
        C13.23,0.544,15.27-0.006,17.441,0c6.844z"
                                  Tag="{TemplateBinding Tag}"
                              >
                                <Path.RenderTransform>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="50"/>
                                </Path.RenderTransform>
                            </Path>
                            <Ellipse Width="21" Height="21" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                     HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                              Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                     />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid Name="grid_pion">
        <ContentControl Name="pion_test" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Tag="4" Content="5" Style="{StaticResource StylePion}" >

        </ContentControl>
</Grid>
```

I want to find a reference to set a rotate transform on it.

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seem `OnApplyTemplate` is for `UserControl` not `ContentControl`

You can write a custom control like this:

```
public class MyControl : ContentControl
{
     public MyControl()
     {
         DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyControl);
     }

     public override void OnApplyTemplate()
     {
         base.OnApplyTemplate();
         var template = this.pion_test.Template;
         var contour = GetTemplateChild("contour_forme");
         forme_path = template.FindName("contour_forme", this.pion_test) as Path;
         Path path = FindVisualChild<Path>(this.pion_test);
         var test = this.pion_test.FindName("contour_forme");
         var test2 = this.pion_test.Template.FindName("contour_forme", this.pion_test);
     }
}
```

And Template:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type MyControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
             <ControlTemplate TargetType="MyControl">
             .....
             </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```